# Sharding is not happening for the second Shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have setup sharding with two nodes (two different hosts). I have 650 MB table. I have chosen Year as the Sharding key. My data has years from 2010 to 2014. I have configured my chunk size as default (which is 64 MB). The result of db.collection.stats is

```js
mongos> db.cTest.stats(1024 * 1024) 
{
       "sharded" : true,
       "ns" : "dbTest.cTest",
       "count" : 244000,
       "numExtents" : 10,
       "size" : 93,
       "storageSize" : 123,
       "totalIndexSize" : 7,
       "indexSizes" : {
               "_id_" : 7
       },
       "avgObjSize" : 0.0003811475409836066,
       "nindexes" : 1,
       "nchunks" : 1,
       "shards" : {
               "shard0001" : {
                       "ns" : "dbTest.cTest",
                       "count" : 244000,
                       "size" : 93,
                       "avgObjSize" : 0.0003811475409836066,
                       "storageSize" : 123,
                       "numExtents" : 10,
                       "nindexes" : 1,
                       "lastExtentSize" : 39,
                       "paddingFactor" : 1,
                       "systemFlags" : 1,
                       "userFlags" : 0,
                       "totalIndexSize" : 7,
                       "indexSizes" : {
                               "_id_" : 7
                       },
                       "ok" : 1
               }
       },
       "ok" : 1 
}
```

I could see that the "sharded" value is equal to "true" and my sh.status shows me the result

```js
mongos> sh.stats
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status ---
sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 3,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
    "currentVersion" : 4,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("53302f0d24ca08864d73449c")
}
shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "localhost:10001" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "mongod0.net:10001" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0002",  "host" : "mongod1.net:10002" }
databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "dbTest",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0001" }
            dbTest.cTest
                    shard key: { "Year" : 1 }
                    chunks:
                            shard0001       1
                    { "Year" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } 
                         -->> { "Year" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0001 Timestamp(1, 0)
```

I am not getting the point that why the shard2 is not getting populated. The chosen key is low cardinality one and the number of rows is evenly distributed for the data.

Where I could have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to force using sh.splitAt on the mongo shell

Comment: but from the shard1, if I populate the table using the following code ::myData = "";while ( myData.length < 200000 )myData += "My data for mongodb sharding";for ( var num = 0; num < 5000; num++ ){db.cTest.save( { myData : myData } );}::: The data is splitting and moving to second shard as well.